# AJAX change in .NET 4: Sys.Services.AuthenticationService

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-ajax, .net-4.0, asp.net-4.0

I'm testing my existing apps in VS 2010, and ran into my first break. ASP.NET AJAX authentication support has changed.

```
Sys.Services.AuthenticationService.set_defaultLogoutCompletedCallback(OnLogoutCompleted);
```

This no longer works. "Sys" is defined, but "Sys.Services" is an undefined object. Does anyone have a quick pointer to the replacement functionality?

EDITED TO ADD:

I've marked this as answered, based on the information that ASP.NET AJAX has changed, and that the client-side AJAX is now separated from the Visual Studio 2010 and .NET 4 distributions. In itself, this is not sufficient for a successful migration, though. Among other things, the current MS AJAX beta does not support the extender wizard in the ASP.NET designer. Also, I haven't found a way to compile successfully with control extenders added in previous releases of ASP.NET AJAX. It looks like AJAX migration will be a tough area for ASP.NET apps in VS 2010.

Around VS 2010 release time, I hope to see a community wiki for migration tips and techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2, it could be your script references. The Microsoft Ajax library is now released out-of-band with the .NET Framework, so script resources that were embedded in System.Web.Extensions have been removed.

You need to download the most recent library from http://ajax.codeplex.com or use the new Microsoft Ajax Content Delivery Network (CDN).

Here are some resources that should help you.

[The Microsoft Ajax Library and Visual Studio Beta 2](http://www.stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/10/21/the-microsoft-ajax-library-and-visual-studio-beta-2.aspx)

[Announcing the Microsoft AJAX CDN](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/announcing-the-microsoft-ajax-cdn.aspx)

Comment: @Rob, thanks for those resource links! It will be another day or so before I have time to check out whether this fixes my problem; I'll update then.